# JQuery do X when scroll reaches an anchor, accurate when resizing

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a navbar with a logo and a hamburger icon that should change colors (fades one version in and fades out the other) when the scroll reaches a certain anchor point. It works well at first but it stops being accurate when I resize the page.

```
var targetOffset = $("#third-home-section").offset().top;

var $w = $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ( $w.scrollTop() > targetOffset ) {   
        navWhite.fadeIn(100);
        navBlack.fadeOut(100);
        hamburgerWhite.fadeIn(100);
        hamburgerBlack.fadeOut(100);

    } else {

        navWhite.fadeOut(100);
        navBlack.fadeIn(100);
        hamburgerWhite.fadeOut(100);
        hamburgerBlack.fadeIn(100);
    }
});
```

Is there any known solution for this problem that I could use in this case?

Comment: Combine it with resize()? - $(window).resize(function(){ ... });

Comment: Wrapping my current function inside? Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to write a jQuery function in a responsive environment is to save the actual function, and call it on a `$(window).resize()`

Seeing as you are running a scrolling function already, you can save your `if` statement (including your variable) inside a function which you run on `$(window).scroll()`, and then add a snippet to run that same function on `$(window).resize()`.

See below example:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    my_responsive_function();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    my_responsive_function();
});

function my_responsive_function() {
    var targetOffset = $("#third-home-section").offset().top;
    if ( $w.scrollTop() > targetOffset ) {   
        navWhite.fadeIn(100);
        navBlack.fadeOut(100);
        hamburgerWhite.fadeIn(100);
        hamburgerBlack.fadeOut(100);
    } else {
        navWhite.fadeOut(100);
        navBlack.fadeIn(100);
        hamburgerWhite.fadeOut(100);
        hamburgerBlack.fadeIn(100);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

As a further explanation of what went wrong with your code, you set your variable `targetOffset` once, it should be set every time the function needs to run.

What essentially happened was `$("#third-home-section").offset().top` has a different value on a different screen size, but if it's set once, it will keep it's value even after the screen size changes. Adding it inside the function forces it to recheck the offset of the element in question.

Comment: This makes scrolling on my page really sluggish.

Answer (score 0):

A minor change and a little bit of golf on @Frits's answer (which was mostly correct)

```
// bind the listener to both events with 'on'
$(window).on('scroll resize', my_responsive_function); 

function my_responsive_function() {
    var targetOffset = $("#third-home-section").offset().top;
    if ( $(this).scrollTop() > targetOffset ) {  // $w was undefined 
        navWhite.fadeIn(100);
        navBlack.fadeOut(100);
        hamburgerWhite.fadeIn(100);
        hamburgerBlack.fadeOut(100);
    } else {
        navWhite.fadeOut(100);
        navBlack.fadeIn(100);
        hamburgerWhite.fadeOut(100);
        hamburgerBlack.fadeIn(100);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** you mentioned 'sluggish' performance, consider `debouncing` the execution of `my_responsive_function` http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

```
// include this jQuery plugin:
// http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.js

// if 'scroll' or 'resize' are triggered more than once per 250ms,
// only the last trigger will actually execute
$(window).on('scroll resize', $.debounce( 250, false, my_responsive_function));
```